# PTX "bit bucket" registers

Tags: assembly, cuda, gpgpu, ptx

...are just mentioned in the [PTX manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/ptx_isa_3.0.pdf). There is no hint about what they are good for or how to use them.

Does anyone know more? Am I just missing a common concept?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (though I most likely am and will be corrected on this ;) ) writes to the register are essentially no-ops.

Comment: In general one specifies a bit-bucket as the destination register for an instruction when one is not interested in the register result produced by the instruction but only in the side-effect of the instruction. For example, with various microprocessors the comparison instruction is actually a pseudo-instruction that is implemented as a subtract instruction with the destination register specified as the bit-bucket, since one is interested only in the flags (conditions codes) generated as a side-effect of the subtraction. harrism already supplied example bit-bucket usage specific to PTX below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bart's comment is basically right. In more detail, as stated in the [PTX ISA 3.1 manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/pdf/ptx_isa_3.1.pdf),

> For some instructions the destination operand is optional.  A “bit bucket” operand 
>   denoted with an underscore (`_`) may be used in place of a destination register.

There is actually only one class of instruction listed in the 3.1 PTX spec for which `_` is a valid destination: `atom`. Here are the semantics of `atom`:

> Atomically loads the original value at location a into destination register d, performs a reduction operation with operand b and the value in location a, and stores the result of the specified operation at location a, overwriting the original value.

And there is a note for `atom`:

> Simple reductions may be specified by using the “bit bucket” destination operand ‘`_`’.

So, we can construct an example:

```
atom.global.add.s32 _, [a], 4
```

This would add 4 to the signed integer at memory location `a`, and not return the previous value of location `a` in a register. So if you don't need the previous value, you can use this.  I assume that the compiler would generate this for this code

```
atomicAdd(&a, 4);
```

since the return value of atomicAdd is not stored to a variable.

Comment: Thank you for expanding on my "something something no-op something" with some actual info. Good to know. :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. And good to know the 3.1 version of the manual is out.